# How to validate and add new users in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, validation

I have created a database and want to register new user in case of absence of that user in database. So, firstly, app checks whether desired username and email exitsts in database or not. If not, it puts new user data into database. I have written code but it goes down when I try to register new user. 
Here is my 
    MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    EditText email, username, password, passwordconf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    public void clickButton2(View view) throws Exception {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        String userName = username.getText().toString();
        String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        if (!ValidateUser(userName, userEmail)) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_LOGIN,
                username.getText().toString());
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_EMAIL, 
                email.getText().toString());
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PASSWORD, 
                password.getText().toString());
            database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            Toast.makeText(this, "you have registered successfully!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, 
                Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
    public boolean ValidateUser(String userName, String userEmail) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, 
        DBHelper.KEY_LOGIN + "=? OR " + DBHelper.KEY_EMAIL + "=?", 
            new String[]{userName, userEmail}, 
            null, null, null);
        int i = cursor.getCount();
        database.close();
        cursor.close();
            if(i>0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

My Database Helper **DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Login_register";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";
    public static final String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "passsword";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT," + 
            KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT"+")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

My layout XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rauf.myapplication.Main2Activity"
android:background="@drawable/bii3">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingRight="58dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="42dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/kamera" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="35dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/message" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="email address"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4a5a71">
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/log"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/usrusr"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="username"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4a5a71"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/red"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/pswrd"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="password"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4a5a71"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/red2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/pswrd"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordconf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="password confirm"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4a5a71">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background2"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:onClick="clickButton2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="clickFunction2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Already have an Account ?"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Assuming that *it goes down* means that it crashes, then you should include the stacktrace from the log. This might be useful if you are unsure as to how and or what the stacktrace is [Analyze a Stack Trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1

You have omitted the **comma** that separates the **KEY_PASSWORD** and **KEY_EMAIL** columns in the **CREATE TABLE** sql.

Thus you are effectively saying `CREATE TABLE users(login TEXT,passsword TEXTemail TEXT)`

That is the table is created with a Column named **login**, with a type of TEXT and a column named **password** with a type of Textemail TEXT and importantly there is no column named email.

Thus any reference to column **email** will then result in that column not being found in the table.

To fix this issue :-

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT," + 
            KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT"+")");`

should be :-

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT," + 
            KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT"+")");`

Note! You should do **one** of the following before rerunning the App after making the above change:-

- Delete the App's Data (via settings).
- Uninstall the App (via settings).
- Increase the Database Version number (i.e. change `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`)

### Issue 2

In the `clickButton2` method you get a writeable SQLIteDatabase instance via `SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

You then invoke the `ValidateUser` and then subsequently try to **insert** a row using the same SQLiteDatabase instance.

However as the `ValidateUser` method closes the database, you will get an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:`

You can easily fix this by one of the following :-

- removing the `database.close()` line from the `ValidateUser` method
- create/open another instance of the SQLiteDatabase before the **insert** e.g  add a line before the insert such as `database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

### Issue 3

If a user already exists and is thus validated they will remain in the MainActivity.

You will need to decide/determine the logic to be used to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've solved the indicated issues and app works as I wanted. I really appreaciate it.